# Using Ramda, and pointfree style, how can I copy the first item of an array to the end of it?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I want to take an array `[1, 2, 3]` and return `[1, 2, 3, 1]`.

I'm using Ramda, and I can get the desired result like this:

```
const fn = arr => R.append(R.prop(0, arr), arr);
```

But I'd like to do it point-free. Here's the closest I've gotten:

```
const fn = R.compose(R.append, R.prop(0));

fn(arr)(arr)
```

But that looks silly. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Try `R.chain(R.prop(0), R.append)` (I hope that functions are monads in ramda)

Comment: This is nice.  I would use `head` over `prop(0)`, but I like it.

Comment: There's currently a bug in `R.chain`. There's a pull request open to fix it: [ramda/ramda#1937](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1937).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge) can be very helpful for things like this.

```
const rotate = R.converge(R.append, [R.head, R.identity])
rotate([1, 2, 3]); //=> [1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Bergi's comment is a better answer.  I just noticed it.

Comment: Well, I understand your answer :) Not sure I get Bergi's answer. How is it better?

Comment: Just that `converge` (and `useWith`) are fairly obscure, and Ramda-specific.  What Bergi used is very standard functions, especially when `chain`, which glues it together, is part of the [FantasyLand Monad](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad) specification.

Answer (score 1):

The [S combinator](https://sanctuary.js.org/#S) is useful here:

```
S.S(S.C(R.append), R.head, [1, 2, 3]);
// => [1, 2, 3, 1]
```