# Bird name for the (=<<) combinator?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinators

The Haskell aviary combinators lists [(=<<)](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Functional.html#v:-61--60--60-) as:

```
(a -> r -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
```

Is there an official bird-name for this? Or can it be derived via the pre-existing ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an official bird-name for this?

I can't find it in [Data.Aviary.Birds](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html), so I suppose there's not. If there was, it probably would've been referenced in the list you linked.

> Or can it be derived via the pre-existing ones?

Surely. The easiest might be to start with the [`starling`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html#v:starling) whose signature is similar, and just compose it with `flip`, i.e.

```
(=<<) = bluebird starling cardinal
```

Comment: Thanks! I had just _applied_ cardinal and starling without composing them - that fixed it :)

Comment: Btw not sure if I am just mixing something up in the order between Haskell <-> Javascript but I ended up with Bluebird Starling Cardinal ... proof of concept: https://repl.it/@DavidKomer/SetFromLens

Comment: @davidkomer also two old my tweets :)
https://twitter.com/xgrommx/status/788346309287809025
https://twitter.com/xgrommx/status/823648079828185088

Comment: @davidkomer and interesting stuff with X combinator
https://twitter.com/xgrommx/status/756801731846103040

Comment: (1) @davidkomer `bluebird starling cardinal` it is indeed (or, in another dialect, `(<*>) . flip`). (2) This definition (and also, possibly, the fact that `(=<<)` isn't regarded as a distinct species of bird) reflects how `(<*>)` and `(=<<)` for functions (the reader functor) [are essentially the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136614/2751851).

Answer (score 4):

maybe will be correctly like: `blackbird warbler bluebird`
this is like

```
(...) = (.) . (.) -- blackbird
(.) -- bluebird
join -- warbler
-- and your function will be 
f = join ... (.)
```

Comment: Btw do you have any advice on how to combine combinators to get a specific signature? I feel like I'm missing some trick (my current technique of staring at a list and doing mental gymnastics doesn't scale too well!)

Comment: This is like LEGO :)

Answer (score 1):

Quoting a comment:

> Btw do you have any advice on how to combine combinators to get a specific signature? I feel like I'm missing some trick (my current technique of staring at a list and doing mental gymnastics doesn't scale too well!)

Let the types guide you. You are looking for:

```
-- This name is totally made-up.
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

While you won't find it in [the list](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-aviary-0.4.0/docs/Data-Aviary-Birds.html), there is something quite similar:

```
starling :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

If only we had a way to somehow twist `starling` into what we want...

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino = f starling
-- f :: ((a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c) -> (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

This mysterious `f` has a rather unwieldy type, so let's abbreviate it for a moment:  with `x ~ b -> a -> c`, `y ~ a -> b -> c` and `z -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`, we have

```
f :: (y -> z) -> x -> z
```

Another look at the list shows this fits the result type of `queer`:

```
queer :: (a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> c
```

Progress!

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino = queer g starling
-- g :: x -> y
-- g :: (b -> a -> c) -> a -> b -> c
```

As for `g`, there is a great candidate near the top of the list:

```
cardinal :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

And there it is:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino = queer cardinal starling
```

`queer`, of course, is `cardinal bluebird` (i.e. reverse function composition), which leads us back to [Bergi's `bluebird starling cardinal`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49413069/2751851).

---

GHC can actually assist you with this kind of derivation:

```
import Data.Aviary.Birds

mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino = _f starling
```

```
GHCi> :l Mino.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Mino.hs, interpreted )

Mino.hs:4:8: error:
    * Found hole:
        _f
          :: ((a0 -> b0 -> c0) -> (a0 -> b0) -> a0 -> c0)
             -> (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
      Where: `b0' is an ambiguous type variable
             `a0' is an ambiguous type variable
             `c0' is an ambiguous type variable
             `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
               at Mino.hs:3:1-43
             `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
               at Mino.hs:3:1-43
             `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
               at Mino.hs:3:1-43
      Or perhaps `_f' is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    * In the expression: _f
      In the expression: _f starling
      In an equation for `mino': mino = _f starling
    * Relevant bindings include
        mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c (bound at Mino.hs:4:1)
  |
4 | mino = _f starling
  |        ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

If you want a clean output, though, you have to ask gently:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}

import Data.Aviary.Birds

mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino =
    let s :: (a -> b -> c) -> _
        s = starling
    in _f s
```

(A type annotation to `starling` would make defining `s` unnecessary; that style, however, would get ugly very quickly with more complicated expressions.)

```
GHCi> :l Mino.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Mino.hs, interpreted )

Mino.hs:10:8: error:
    * Found hole:
        _f
          :: ((a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c)
             -> (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
      Where: `b' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
               at Mino.hs:6:1-57
             `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
               at Mino.hs:6:1-57
             `c' is a rigid type variable bound by
               the type signature for:
                 mino :: forall b a c. (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
               at Mino.hs:6:1-57
      Or perhaps `_f' is mis-spelled, or not in scope
    * In the expression: _f
      In the expression: _f s
      In the expression:
        let
          s :: (a -> b -> c) -> _
          s = starling
        in _f s
    * Relevant bindings include
        s :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c (bound at Mino.hs:9:9)
        mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c (bound at Mino.hs:7:1)
   |
10 |     in _f s
   |        ^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

---

The process described above still involves quite a bit of staring at the list, as we are working it out using nothing but the birds in their pointfree majesty. Without such constraints, though, we would likely proceed in a different manner:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino g f = _
```

The hole has type `a -> c`, so we know it is a function that takes an `a`:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino g f = \x -> _
-- x :: a
```

The only other thing that takes an `a` here is `g`:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino g f = \x -> g _ x
```

The type of the hole is now `b`, and the only thing that gives out a `b` is `f`:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino g f = \x -> g (f x) x
```

This, of course, is the usual definition of the reader `(=<<)`. If we flip `g`, though...

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino g f = \x -> flip g x (f x)
```

... the reader `(<*>)` (i.e. the S combinator) becomes recogniseable:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino g f = \x -> (<*>) (flip g) f x
```

We can then write it pointfree...

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino = (<*>) . flip
```

... and translate to birdspeak:

```
mino :: (b -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
mino = bluebird starling cardinal
```