# Does the usage of right-applied composition operator hint that contramap could be used?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, idioms, pointfree

### Long story short

I'm wandering if I should think of using `contramap` when I find myself writing code like `(. f) . g`, where `f` is in practice preprocessing the second argument to `g`.

### Long story longer

I will describe how I came up with the code that made me think of the question in the title.

Initially, I had two inputs, `a1 :: In` and `a2 :: In`, wrapped in a pair `(a1, a2) :: (In,In)`, and I needed to do two interacting processing on those inputs. Specifically, I had a function `binOp :: In -> In -> Mid` to generate a "temporary" result, and a function `fun :: Mid -> In -> In -> Out` to be fed with `binOp`'s **inputs *and* output**.

Given the part "function fed with inputs and output of another function" above, I though of using the function monad, so I came up with this,

```hs
finalFun = uncurry . fun =<< uncurry binOp
```

which isn't very complicated to read: `binOp` takes the inputs as a pair, and passes its output followed by its inputs to `fun`, which takes the inputs as a pair too.

However, I noticed that in the implementation of `fun` I was actually using only a "reduced" version of the inputs, i.e. I had a definition like `fun a b c = fun' a (reduce b) (reduce c)`, so I thougth that, instead of `fun`, I could use `fun'`, alongside `reduce`, in the definition of `finalFun`; I came up with

```hs
finalFun = (. both reduce) . uncurry . fun' =<< uncurry binOp
```

which is far less easy to read, especially because it features an un-natural order of the parts, I believe. I could only think of using some more descriptive name, as in

```hs
finalFun = preReduce . uncurry . fun' =<< uncurry binOp
    where preReduce = (. both reduce)
```

Since `preReduce` is actually pre-processing the 2nd and 3rd argument of `fun'`, I was wandering if this is the right moment to use `contramap`.

Comment: Not sure about `contramap`, but another alternative you might want to consider is `finalFun = curry $ fun' <$> uncurry binOp <*> (reduce.fst) <*> (reduce.snd)`.

Comment: This actually sounds somewhat profunctor-ish, where you want to transform the input *and* the output. For functions, `dimap f g h == h . g . f`

Comment: @chepner I think you meant `dimap f g h == g . h . f`

Comment: Yeah, I always have trouble remembering whether `f` comes first or last, then I got lazy and just rattled them off in right-to-left order.

Comment: @bradrn it looks like the applicative style just doesn't stick in my head.

Comment: But there's no `Contravariant` instance for functions...?

Comment: @DanielWagner Oops! Thanks for correcting this collective thinko. I guess we can follow chepner's lead and use `lmap` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lmap f . g` ([rather than `contramap`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66300535/does-the-usage-of-right-applied-composition-operator-hint-that-contramap-could-b/66303963#comment117219519_66300535), as that would also require an `Op` wrapper) might indeed be an improvement over `(. f) . g` in terms of clarity. If your readers are familiar with `Profunctor`, seeing `lmap` will promptly suggest the input to something is being modified, without the need for them to perform dot plumbing in their heads. Note it isn't a widespread idiom yet, though. (For reference, here are Serokell Hackage Search queries for [the `lmap` version](https://hackage-search.serokell.io/?q=%5Cblmap+%5B%5B%3Aalpha%3A%5D%7C0-9%5D%2B+%5C.+%5B%5B%3Aalpha%3A%5D%7C0-9%5D%2B) and [the dot section one](https://hackage-search.serokell.io/?q=%5C%28%5C.+%5B%5B%3Aalpha%3A%5D%7C0-9%5D%2B%5C%29+%5C.+%5B%5B%3Aalpha%3A%5D%7C0-9%5D%2B).)

As for your longer example, the idiomatic thing to do would probably be not writing it pointfree. That said, we can get a more readable pointfree version by changing the argument order of `fun`/`fun'`, so that you can use the [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40136614/2751851) `Applicative` instance instead of the `Monad` one:

```
binOp :: In -> In -> Mid
fun' :: In -> In -> Mid -> Out
reduce :: In -> In

both f = bimap f f

finalFun :: (In, In) -> Out
finalFun = uncurry fun' . both reduce <*> uncurry binOp
```

Pointfree function `(<*>)` is arguably less hard to make sense of than pointfree function `(=<<)`, as its two arguments are computations in the relevant function functor. Also, this change removes the need for the dot section trick. Lastly, since `(.)` is `fmap` for functions, we can further rephrase `finalFun` as...

```
finalFun = uncurry fun' <$> both reduce <*> uncurry binOp
```

... thus getting an applicative style expression, which in my (not so popular!) opinion is a reasonably readable way of using the function applicative. (We might further streamline it using `liftA2`, but I feel that in this specific scenario makes it less obvious what is going on.)

Comment: Indeed a very elegant solution. I'll try that out!