# What is a functional programming design pattern for adding new data to the flow a function pipeline

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ecmascript-6, lodash, ramda.js

I'm new to functional programming and working with es6 javascript and the lodash functional programming library. I wanted to know how you experienced vets would go about handling the following:

```
const foo = origObj => {

   // use origObj to produce additional information called newObj, 
   // that is used in the next function

   return newObj
}

const bar = (origObj, newObj) => {

  // use both origObj and newObj
  // to produce some final output

  return finalOutput     
}

const myFunction = _.flow(
  foo,
  bar
)

// call myFunction with some object
myFunction({})
```

The problem here is that I need to access both the `origObj` values and the `newObj` values in `bar` and right now `bar` would only receive `newObj`. I'm wondering what are some functional programing design patterns for addressing this issue.  I've been doing something like this:

```
const foo = data => {
   // use data.origObj to produce additional information called newObj, 
   // that is used in the next function
   return newObj
}

// now accepts a object that contains both the original and
// new object as keys
const bar = data => {

  // use both data.origObj and data.newObj
  // to produce some final output

  return finalOutput     
}

// `assignResultAs` takes a function `func` and string `key`.
// It returns a function that takes some `data` object and returns
// a shallow copy of `data` with the result of `func`
// being called with `data` assigned to the copy 
// as the value to `key`
const assignResultAs = (func, key) => data => ({
  ...data, 
  [key]: func(data)
}) 

const myFunction = _.flow(
  assignResultAs(foo, 'newObj'),
  bar
)

myFunction({ 
  origObj: {} 
})
```

In my functional programming attempts this problem keeps coming up where I need to pass not only the original data that I started with in my functional pipeline but also additional computations that were derived from the original data to the remaining functions.  What functional programming patterns exist to do this? Does lodash and/or Ramda have anything specific to deal with this?

Comment: I could help you better if you pasted your actual code - it sounds to me like you don't even need function composition or `flow` for this

Comment: I can paste some code in but I'm afraid the discussion might spiral into many other topics.

Comment: My concern is that you're trying to fit a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: It's possible `flow` is not needed, and surely for this contrived example it's not needed. Given the constraints that I've described above, how would you go about passing arguments between the function in a functional programming sort of way?

Comment: If you feel like this is not enough information, I'll put up some more concrete code later today. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Well functional composition works great when functions take one value and return one value. It breaks down when you starting taking/receiving more than one. As you're already aware, pass a arrays or objects can help you get around this, but I can't really help you further without seeing your code.

Comment: To my understanding you need `let b = f(a), c = g(a,b)` - what's wrong with writing it exactly like that?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026018/ for a slightly different approach.